# Using conditions with django template tags/filters?

Tags: python, django, templates, filter, tags

If I'm using `{% spaceless %}<html></html>{% endspaceless %}` in my templates, but I only want the spaceless function on only when I'm not debugging, how can do this?  I tried using `{% if %}{% spaceless %}{% endif %}` , but that's an error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote just such a tag and put it on Django Snippets: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2405/ Enjoy!

Comment: thx, but to do this for any filter/tag, one would have to create a custom tag for each one?

Comment: Hi @Derek. I suppose you could create a base class that inherits from template.Node and adds settings as a property. Then you'd be able to have access to DEBUG in any template node that extends it.